# Blocking queue with order guarantee

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, queue, priority-queue

I have 8 threads that process an image in strips. The strips are ordered in raster order. When each thread is finished with a strip, the thread adds its strip id number to a blocking queue. I want the queue to only allow a pop when the number is in sequence from 0 to N.  So, regardless of the order in which the threads add their IDs, the queue output will be 0,1,2,3,.....N.
Is there an existing construct in the STL that has this functionality ?

I suppose a simple implementation would be a vanilla queue with a counter starting at 0. When 0 gets added, it pops and moves the counter to 1, and keeps popping until it doesn't find a match. But this sounds inefficient.

Edit: if I wrap an STL priority queue to make it blocking, this could work.

Comment: Why a queue?  A collection of elements in order is called an array.  Just write directly to the corresponding element as each strip is completed.

Comment: the strips are processed out of order - another thread will write them to disk in order. Thus, a queue.

Comment: I faced a similar problem in Java. PriorityBlockingQueue wasn't sufficient because I wanted to block until sequentially next item is enqueued. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66541105/10026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you want is a min heap (see `std::priority_queue`). This gives the element with the lowest ID.

Wake up the consumer thread every time the newly added element is at the beginning of the queue.

Consume all elements that are in sequence in one go.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a queue at all! Queue should only support push_back and pop_front. There is no peeking inside.

I would suggest a `map<ID,image>`, and maintain the last processed image ID. Then you can quickly check if that map's `front()` is next in your sequence, and remove it.