# What's the purpose of the PriorityBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, priority-queue, java.util.concurrent

I've been [playing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66541105/10026) with blocking queues and `PriorityQueue`, and it got me thinking. I can't see a good usecase for `PriorityBlockingQueue`. The point of a priority queue is to sort the values put into it before they're retrieved. A blocking queue implies that values are inserted into it and retrieved from it concurrently. But, if that's the case, you'd never be able to guarantee the sort order.

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();

new Thread (()->{ randomSleep(); q.put(2); randomSleep(); q.put(0); }).start();
new Thread (()->{ randomSleep(); q.put(3); randomSleep(); q.put(1); }).start();

ArrayList<Integer> ordered = new ArrayList<>(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    randomSleep();
    ordered.add(q.take());
}
System.out.println(ordered);
```

In this example, the order in which the main thread gets the offered values is quite random, which seems to defeat the purpose of a priority queue. Even with a single producer and single consumer, the order can not be ensured.

So, what is the use of `PriorityBlockingQueue` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this example, the order in which the main thread gets the offered
> values is quite random

Well you have a race-condition during the insertion and the retrieve of those elements. Hence, the reason why it looks random.

Nonetheless, you could use for instance the `PriorityBlockingQueue` to sequentially field up with some elements (or tasks) that need to be pick up by multiple threads in parallel by **their highest priority element/task**. In such case you can take advantage of the thread-safe properties of a structure that guarantees you that the **the highest priority element is always ordered first.**

One example would be a Queue of tasks in which those tasks have a priority, and you want those same tasks to be processed in parallel.